# Facebook API user request limit reached

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, azure-databricks

I am trying to retrieve facebook ads using the facebook_ad_accounts when trying to retreive it I am getting the below error. Is there a way to increase the user limit?

Facebook request error:

```
message:call was not successful
Method:get
status:400 
message:User request limit reached
is_transient:true
code:17
error_subcode:2446079
fbtrace_id:""
```

Changes tried

1. Made changes to the code with retry interval with max interval as 3
   in databricks(python).
2. Tried executing the accounts in batches first 250 then the next etc.
   But didn't help

Comment: Check the `X-App-Usage` HTTP header to see how close your app is to its limit and when you can resume making calls when the limit has been reached.

Comment: @ArpitJain- How to check if the X-App-Usage?